# Updating Python 3.4x to 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

just a quick question. I have Python 2.7 on my mac by default. I have also installed 3.4 and use it more than 2.7, but would like to upgrade to the new 3.5. Should I remove 3.4 and just lay down a new install of 3.5, or is there a way to just update it. All my searches just talk about upgrading from 2.7 to 3x. I am just concerned about messing one of the installs up. Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: It depends on how they are packaged which you didn't specify

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure what you mean by packaged. My mac had python 2.x installed by default, and I installed 3.x from python.org, keeping 2.x as the default setting, and using 3.x by terminal command python3, or just opening idle3.

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot safer to change your environment so that Python 3.5 is given preference over the default Python.

There are many ways to do this; if you do them all, it provides the maximum compatibility.

You can set these in your `.bash_profile` file, which is a hidden file in your home directory.

1. You can set the `PATH` environment variable so that Python 3.5 appears first in the search order; like this `PATH='/path/to/your/python3.5/directory':$PATH`
2. You can set a local alias in your shell, so that the `python` command points to Python 3.5, like this `alias python="/path/to/the/file/python3.5"`

Once you set the above, make sure you restart the terminal application.

If you download the installer form python.org; it will set these environment variables for you.

Also, if you use a utility like `brew` it will set the shell up correctly for you.

This will ensure that the shell environment will point to version of Python you want; however this does not affect applications that run on the *desktop* as most of them don't read the shell environment variables.

So, if you are using and IDE like PyCharm you'll still have to manually set the correct Python version for your projects.

This may seem like a lot of workaround, but on most Linux systems and even on OSX, Python is a core part of the system and it is used by some utilities, therefore it is always dangerous to rip and replace the version of Python that came with the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.Up to now,  I have kept the default version set to 2.7 so I didn't mess anything up, as I don't know a whole lot about it,  and just specifically opened 3.4 when I was playing around and going through tutorials typing python3 into terminal.